# Create a Javascript Gallery with Background Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, gallery

Need help creating a full page gallery. I tried various options. I'm trying to create full page gallery that lets the user scroll vertically though 1 image at a time.

Here's my code:

```
<style>

#img1 {
background-image: url("<?php echo $image ;?>");
height:100vh !Important;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#img2 {
background-image: url("<?php echo $image2 ;?>");
height:100vh !Important;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#img3 {
background-image: url("<?php echo $image3 ;?>");
height:100vh !Important;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<div id="img1"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
<div id="img2"></div>
```

I'm stuck on the javascript/jquery solution to detect if the user has scrolled. I want to change images if the user scrolls up 10 pixels or down 10 pixels.

Here's an example of what I'm trying achieve:
http://themes.themegoods.com/photome/demo/gallery-archive/gallery-archive-fullscreen/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use js libs like "fullPage.js, smart scroll, pagePiling.js" those help you to make a perfect page or gallery scroll like what you wanted to achieve, for more information follows below links:

- https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
- http://blog.danyll.com/smartscroll-jquery-scrolljacking-plugin/
- https://alvarotrigo.com/pagePiling/